# Grouping tests in pytest: Classes vs plain functions

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest to test my app.
pytest supports 2 approaches (that I'm aware of) of how to write tests:

1. In classes:

> test_feature.py -> class TestFeature -> def test_feature_sanity

2. In functions:

> test_feature.py -> def test_feature_sanity

Is the approach of grouping tests in a class needed? Is it allowed to backport unittest builtin module?
Which approach would you say is better and why?

Comment: As it's mentioned in `pytest` documentation, you can use it to execute `unittest` tests. As for grouping tests in a class, it's mostly a matter of taste and organization.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There are no strict rules regarding organizing tests into modules vs classes. It is a matter of personal preference. Initially I tried organizing tests into classes, after some time I realized I had no use for another level of organization. Nowadays I just collect test functions into modules (files).

I could see a valid use case when some tests could be logically organized into same file, but still have additional level of organization into classes (for instance to make use of class scoped fixture). But this can also be done just splitting into multiple modules.

Comment: I would like to strengthen what Zim says about making use of class-scoped fixtures by proposing that this is the primary reason to group tests in a class. If you don't need the "fixture nesting" provided by having a class-scoped fixture (which operates intentionally within your module- and session-scoped fixtures) I would say there's no reason to have a class.

Comment: My use-case for grouping tests using classes - is to allow for mutual setups/teardowns to happen once for each group of tests/class. I cannot imagine how to do that using functions and module files.

Answer (score 119):

This answer presents two compelling use-cases for a TestClass in pytest:

- Joint parametrization of multiple test methods belonging to a given class.
- Reuse of test data and test logic via subclass inheritance

### Joint parametrization of multiple test methods belonging to a given class.

The pytest parametrization decorator, [`@pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html), can be used to make inputs available to multiple methods within a class. In the code below, the inputs `param1` and `param2` are available to each of the methods `TestGroup.test_one` and `TestGroup.test_two`.

```py
# in file `test_class_parametrization.py`
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("param1", "param2"),
    [
        ("a", "b"),
        ("c", "d"),
    ],
)
class TestGroup:
    """A class with common parameters, `param1` and `param2`."""

    @pytest.fixture
    def fixt(self) -> int:
        """This fixture will only be available within the scope of TestGroup"""
        return 123

    def test_one(self, param1: str, param2: str, fixt: int) -> None:
        print("\ntest_one", param1, param2, fixt)

    def test_two(self, param1: str, param2: str) -> None:
        print("\ntest_two", param1, param2)
```

```
$ pytest -s test_class_parametrization.py
================================================================== test session starts ==================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/jbss
plugins: pylint-0.18.0
collected 4 items

test_class_parametrization.py
test_one a b 123
.
test_one c d 123
.
test_two a b
.
test_two c d
.

=================================================================== 4 passed in 0.01s ===================================================================
```

### Reuse of test data and test logic via subclass inheritance

I'll use a modified version of code taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044620/4256346) to demonstrate the usefulness of inheriting class attributes/methods from `TestClass` to `TestSubclass`:

```py
# in file `test_inheritance.py`
class TestClass:
    VAR: int = 3
    DATA: int = 4

    def test_var_positive(self) -> None:
        assert self.VAR >= 0


class TestSubclass(TestClass):
    VAR: int = 8

    def test_var_even(self) -> None:
        assert self.VAR % 2 == 0

    def test_data(self) -> None:
        assert self.DATA == 4
```

Running `pytest` on this file causes **four** tests to be run:

```
$ pytest -v test_inheritance.py
=========== test session starts ===========
platform linux -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1
collected 4 items

test_inheritance.py::TestClass::test_var_positive PASSED
test_inheritance.py::TestSubclass::test_var_positive PASSED
test_inheritance.py::TestSubclass::test_var_even PASSED
test_inheritance.py::TestSubclass::test_data PASSED
```

In the subclass, the inherited `test_var_positive` method is run using the updated value `self.VAR == 8`, and the newly defined `test_data` method is run against the inherited attribute `self.DATA == 4`. Such method and attribute inheritance gives a flexible way to re-use or modify shared functionality between different groups of test-cases.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm a pytest novice, but couldn't `fixt` just as well be defined outside the `TestGroup` class, and then just requested where needed?

Comment: @JonT It certainly could. As far as I know, the only practical difference between defining `fixt` inside vs outside of `TestGroup` comes down to matters of scope.

Comment: It appears I should be using classes to do tests instead of just plain py files to make testing more reuseable. Appreciate the aggregate of information, this deserves the 100 upvotes.

Answer (score 40):

Typically in unit testing, the object of our tests is a single function. That is, a single function gives rise to multiple tests. In reading through test code, it's useful to have tests for a single unit be grouped together in some way (which also allows us to e.g. run all tests for a specific function), so this leaves us with two options:

1. Put all tests for each function in a dedicated module
2. Put all tests for each function in a class

In the first approach we would still be interested in grouping all tests related to a source module (e.g. `utils.py`) in some way. Now, since we are already using modules to group tests for a *function*, this means that we should like to use a *package* to group tests for a source module.

The result is one source *function* maps to one test *module*, and one source *module* maps to one test *package*.

In the second approach, we would instead have one source function map to one test class (e.g. `my_function()` -> `TestMyFunction`), and one source module map to one test module (e.g. `utils.py` -> `test_utils.py`).

It depends on the situation, perhaps, but the second approach, i.e. a class of tests for each function you are testing, seems more clear to me. Additionally, if we are testing source *classes*/methods, then we could simply use an inheritance hierarchy of test classes, and still retain the one source module -> one test module mapping.

Finally, another benefit to either approach over just a flat file containing tests for multiple functions, is that with classes/modules already identifying which function is being tested, you can have better names for the actual tests, e.g. `test_does_x` and `test_handles_y` instead of `test_my_function_does_x` and `test_my_function_handles_y`.