# Replacement for test case inheritance in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

### Background

In Python's [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) framework, it is a fairly common idiom to use inheritance on a base set of tests to apply an entire set of tests to a new problem, and occasionally to add additional tests. A trivial example would be:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    VAR = 3

    def test_var_positive(self):
        self.assertGreaterEqual(self.VAR, 0)

class SubTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    VAR = 8

    def test_var_even(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.VAR % 2 == 0)
```

Which, when run, runs 3 tests:

```
$ python -m unittest -v
test_var_positive (test_unittest.BaseTestCase) ... ok
test_var_even (test_unittest.SubTestCase) ... ok
test_var_positive (test_unittest.SubTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s
```

This is particularly useful if you are testing a class hierarchy, where each subclass [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) subtype of the parent classes, and should thus be able to pass the parent class's test suite in addition to its own.

### Problem

I would like to switch over to using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), but I have a lot of tests that are structured this way. From what I can tell, `pytest` intends to replace most of the functionality of `TestCase` classes with fixtures, but **is there a pytest idiom that allows test inheritance, and if so what is it**?

I am aware that `pytest` can be used to run `unittest`-style tests, but [the support is limited](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses), and I would like to use some of the "will never be supported" features of `pytest` in my tests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pytest allows you to group test cases in classes, so it naturally has support for test case inheritance.

When rewriting your `unittest` tests to `pytest` tests, remember to follow [pytest's naming guidelines](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery):

- class names must begin with `Test`
- function/method names must begin with `test_`

Failing to comply with this naming scheme will prevent your tests from being collected and executed.

---

Your tests rewritten for pytest would look like this:

```
class TestBase:
    VAR = 3

    def test_var_positive(self):
        assert self.VAR >= 0

class TestSub(TestBase):
    VAR = 8

    def test_var_even(self):
        assert self.VAR % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not compatible with classes that implement __init__, because Pytest will refuse to run those.