# Testing in pandas library: Why is function style chosen over class based testing?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

Why is functional style testing facilitating testing compared to class based testing? Is this just additional library specific functionality or are there any general reasons to adopt functional style testing patterns?

To quote from [pandas development guidelines](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_codebase.html#test-driven-development-code-writing):

pandas existing test structure is mostly class-based, meaning that you will typically find tests wrapped in a class.

```
class TestReallyCoolFeature:  
    pass
```

Going forward, we are moving to a more functional style using the pytest framework, which offers a richer testing framework that will facilitate testing and developing. Thus, instead of writing test classes, we will write test functions like this:

```
def test_really_cool_feature():
    pass
```

Comment: On a related matter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50016862/11246056

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation in this [PR comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15608#issuecomment-284892889). In short, the move from class-based testing to function-based testing is a consequence of pandas switching from nose to pytest.

Before the switch, almost every test was a method of a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`. pytest has very good support for running `unittest` tests, but there are some pytest features that can't be used inside `unittest.TestCase` subclasses. These incompatible features are listed in the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses). One of them is `@pytest.mark.parametrize`. As the PR comment explains, the desire to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` motivated the change in testing style.